# How to Animate a Live Wallpaper Android

Tags: animation, live-wallpaper, android

We are trying to develop a live wallpaper for Android phones, but when it comes to the animation part and the size of the APK we are a bit stuck.

We tried Sprite animation and PNG frame by frame animation, both consumes large amounts of space (over 10MB for less than 2sec animation) in the phone due to the size of PNG images or Sprite stripes.

But I have seen some live wallpapers in the App Market which has amazing animations but the APK size is less than 1MB. Is there a way to achieve this? if so any assistance from anyone would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ones that take up very little space are the ones that do a lot of the drawing on the fly, rather than using sprites. I'm sure you've read this link, but just in case you haven't: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html

Comment: @xbonez, I thought so too, but is there a tutorial on how to draw complex images on the fly? i'm no animator nor an artist... I will also try to google up some resources for same. Thankz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first approach, I would suggest you to try the andengine platform and its livewallpaper extension (http://www.andengine.org/). Since the platform developers have dealt with lots of similiar issues, I think there is no reason for you to reivent the wheel. AndEngine platform has many memory and speed optimization features, specially on the GLES2 release, and it is free and opensource.